# Conditional scales number format in ggplot function

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to write a shiny module to display a basic ggplot object.
I'd like to have a parameter "y_labels_type" to change the axis labels like:

`scales::number_format( accuracy = 0.1)` if `y_labels_type` is not set

or

`scales::dollar_format(prefix = "", suffix = "\u20ac")` if `y_labels_type` is equal to "euro".

Is this something possible? So far my code throw an error:

> Warning: Error in [: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
> 54: case_when
> 53: module [modules/basic_trend_plot.R#44]
> 48: callModule
> 47: server [.../server.R#29]
> Error in value[[1]][rep(NA_integer_, m)] :
> object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

```
basic_trended_plot_module_srv <- function(input, output, session,
                                      data="data",
                                      yaxis=y,
                                      xaxis=x,
                                      y_labels_type=NULL) {

y_labels_scale <-  scales::number_format( accuracy = 0.1)

y_labels_scale = case_when(
    y_labels_type == "euro" ~ scales::dollar_format(prefix = "", suffix = "\u20ac")
)

output$trend_plot_out <- renderPlot({
    plot <- data %>%
        ggplot(
            aes(x={{xaxis}},y={{yaxis}})
            )+
            geom_area(color="dodgerblue4",fill="dodgerblue3",alpha=0.6)+
            scale_color_brewer(palette = "Greens")+
            scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens")+
            scale_y_continuous(labels = y_labels_scale )
    #ggplotly(plot)
    return(plot)
})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got very stupid error.
The problem was in the case_when statement. Just remove it and everything works fine:

```
y_labels_scale <-  scales::number_format( accuracy = 1, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = " ")
    if (!is.null(y_labels_type)){
        if (y_labels_type == "euro") y_labels_scale <- scales::dollar_format(prefix = "", suffix = "\u20ac")
    }

output$trend_plot_out <- renderPlot({
    plot <- data %>%
        ggplot(
            aes(x={{xaxis}},y={{yaxis}})
            )+
            geom_area(color="dodgerblue4",fill="dodgerblue3",alpha=0.6)+
            scale_color_brewer(palette = "Greens")+
            scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens")+
            scale_y_continuous(labels = y_labels_scale )
    #ggplotly(plot)
    return(plot)
})
```